# Ideal Opamp Input terminals doubt

Tags: operational-amplifier

For an Ideal Opamp since the input terminals are virtually short circuited we dont need to worry about which input terminal is inv and which one is non-inv. Should I be careful while making this assumption? Thanks.

Comment: Sure you have! I  think you have to do a higher effort on your researches. There's a lot of possible setups on opamp that depends on how you are using each terminal as input and feedback. The wikipedia can be a good start point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input terminals of an op-amp only become "virtually shorted" when negative feedback is applied. Negative feedback requires that the inverting terminal is used for the feedback. This means we do need to worry about which terminal we use or positive feedback could happen and we get an oscillator or we get a circuit that just does not work as a linear amplifier.

Comment: or maybe a schimtt trigger device

Comment: @PedroQuadros [Schmitt trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Schmitt)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger

Comment: @PedroQuadros - the guy in Spehro's link invented the schmitt trigger in your link.

Comment: Yeah, I've ready his story when I was studying opamps and he was absolutely fantastic. He was very premature, at age of about 20 he had already had lots of achievements

Answer (score 3):

> For an Ideal Opamp since the input terminals are virtually short
>   circuited we dont need to worry about which input terminal is inv and
>   which one is non-inv.

I'm not sure how you came to this conclusion.

First, to be clear, the *virtual short circuit* assumption holds *only* in the case that there is net negative feedback.

However, it is not the case that, given net negative feedback, the two input terminals are *actually* connected to the same circuit node.

The easiest way to see this is to consider the simple unity gain non-inverting amplifier configuration for an op-amp with *finite* open-loop gain \$A_{vo}\$.

One can solve the circuit easily to find that the output voltage is

$$v_O = v_- = \frac{A_{vo}}{1 + A_{vo}}v_+$$

In the limit as \$A_{vo} \rightarrow \infty\$, we have

$$v_O = v_- = v_+$$

Now, 'switch' the non-inverting and inverting terminals around and solve to find

$$v_O = v_+ =  \frac{-A_{vo}}{1 - A_{vo}}v_-$$

This is clearly a *different* result from above so it is not true that "we don't need to worry about which input terminal is inv and which one is non-inv.".

It is true that, in the limit as the open-loop gain goes to infinity, we recover the result

$$v_O = v_- = v_+$$

however, it turns out that, for the 2nd case, we have *positive* feedback (the negative sign in the denominator is the clue) and the circuit is unstable; the circuit will act to *maximize* the difference in the input terminal voltages rather than *minimize* it.

Answer (score 1):

That assumption is only true when the op-amp is in a stable balance. Think about what happens if the terminals are reversed and there is a very small imbalance in the voltage- does the output drive to correct the imbalance or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a correct assumption. You do need to pay attention to which input terminal is which.

There is no such thing as an ideal op amp. Ideal op amp is just a heuristic we use to analyze a closed-loop system, by removing the op-amp and making some assumptions about how a properly operating closed-loop system will behave.

In reality, the negative feedback connected to the inverting input terminal, drives the inverting input to *almost* the same voltage as the non-inverting input. But not quite the same voltage, because the op-amp has finite open-loop gain.